# How can I display a Success Message on transition at the source page? (Oracle APEX 21.1)

Tags: oracle-apex

I have 2 pages in an application. P11 (Name: `BASE FORM PAGE`. It is Normal Page) and P12 (Name: `SHOP DATA COMMIT DIALOG`. It is a Modal Dialog.)

`SHOP DATA COMMIT DIALOG` has a form. This form is working for registration a shop data to the Database.
When success to insert a data to DB, I want close this dialog, and display message on right up side of the `BASE FORM PAGE`.

It would be better if the name of the store entered in the dialog could be included in the message. Like `"Success! Add a data of :P12_SHOP_NAME"`.

I have tried some settings on `SHOP DATA COMMIT DIALOG` page. But it does not show me a message on `BASE FORM PAGE`.

1. `Processes - Identification: [Close Dialog]`. I set a value in `Settings - Item to Return`.
2. `Processes - Identification: [Close Dialog]`. I set a value in `Success Message`.

Seriously it is not easy to me. Is there anyone to give me an answer or something hint?

Thank you for your kindness to read this message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a Modal dialog page, there's the "Process form" process whose type is "Automatic Row Processing (DML)" - Apex creates it automatically. It is responsible for inserting new rows or updating (or deleting) existing ones.

By default, when you create (or apply changes), it returns a built-in message (e.g. "Row updated"). If you want to change the message, navigate to process' properties, scroll down to "Success Message" property and type something like this in there:

```
Success! Add a data of &P12_SHOP_NAME.
```

Pay attention to leading `&` and trailing `.` for `&P12_SHOP_NAME.`

So, when you create a new row, you'll see

> Success! Add a data of ZARA

message in upper right corner of the *Normal* page.

Comment: Shop names are appear! It makes me happy thing :D
But it display only when remove a process "Close Dialog". This message show on the popup page. I tried several times but could not find where it was wrong. Please let me try a few and ask additional questions if they don't work.